# Set a pastebin as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, pastebin

I have a variable in a pastebin file and i was wondering if i could get my java script to use it?
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j2Rm33fS)

I thought maybe:

```
<script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j2Rm33fS"></script>
```

But its a php file and for some reason when i reason when i try to display this it displays as [Object] or just nothing.

I even tried removing the variables and making them only available in the pastebin but then none of the variables showed...

Comment: It works for me. If I put `alert(Dump)` in a script after that, it displays it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet works fine for me.

But, the fact is the `Content-Type` of the URL `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j2Rm33fS` is `plain/text`. Some browser may ignore it for security reason.

```js
alert(Dump);
```

```html
<script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j2Rm33fS"></script>
```